# what is the fallacy when someone misrepresents someone's views but acts as if they're not

Tags: logic, fallacies

For example, when Doctor X says "its bad when celiac compromised people eat gluten", then in an argument I say "its bad when everyone eats gluten, not just celiac compromised people. I know this is true because Doctor X said so in his book (etc)". Here I quote the Doctor X but misrepresent his views to further my agenda. What would this fallacy be called? Thank you

Comment: It is not a fallacy, it is called lying. And if they act like they are telling the truth when they are lying, they are called good liars.

Comment: in a court of law, where such misrepresentation is impermissible, it is called *misrepresentation of previous testimony*. The reason it is impermissible is that this method is very effective at swaying juries to arrive at wrong verdicts.

Answer (score 1):

In a court of law, where such misrepresentation is impermissible, it is called *mischaracterization of previous testimony*. The reason it is impermissible is that this method (also called *lying*) is very effective at swaying juries to arrive at unjust verdicts.

For this very reason, trial lawyers will try to get away with it as often as possible, which causes opposing counsel to repeatedly jump to their feet and say, "Objection! Mischaracterizes previous testimony!"

Answer (score 0):

When you misrepresent someone's views for the purpose of *refuting* them, it's a strawman fallacy.  What you described is related to the [fallacy of quoting out of context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_quoting_out_of_context), although in your case it is paraphrasing out of context.

Comment: thank you so much !!